# Which framework for HTML5 applications with native code and widgets?

Tags: wpf, node.js, node-webkit, chromium-embedded

I need to develop hybrid applications (imagine something like a rich text editor) for Windows, Mac, Android and iOS.

So I'm looking for a framework where I can:

1. Use HTML5 + Node.js in a native app.
2. Use native code as libraries (for example for monitor screenshots)
3. Use some native widgets for a better user experience.

For requirements 1 and 2 I can use Node-Webkit or Brackets Shell and Node-Gyp. 
But what for requirements 3?

Maybe some like WPF Chromium (for Windows) but how can I use also Node.js in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use native widgets, you will need a bridge or several ones that match the platform/devices you want to target. IMO you'll lose the benefit of what node-webkit offers, which is having JS/nodeJS on the whole stack and HTML5 for a versatile UI.

Many third-parties HTML5/JS/NodeJS fulfil almost all your needs. What are the particular widgets you are interested in?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
I need native toolbars. For example a ribbon toolbar in Windows.

Maybe QT with a webviewer can be my answer.

Comment: If so use jQuery ribbon plugin. Remember node-webkit is all about Chromium (= Chrome as open source, which is a very capable browser in terms of HTML/JS/CSS3) and nodeJS. The jQuery ribbon can be implemented once and deployed to all the platform you want to target. http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/tag/jquery-ribbon-bar/

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.